# jooq fails to store the data in the given table

Tags: java, jooq, discord-jda

I have tried to find out what the problem but I have had not luck so far so I have decided to ask on here.

So my problem is that when I run the command /log_channel set add_channel: channelid
it does not update the database and does not give any waring or error the code is

```java
public static void setLogChannel(long guildId, long channelId) {
        getContext().insertInto(LOG_CHANNEL)
            .set(LOG_CHANNEL.GUILD_ID, guildId)
            .set(LOG_CHANNEL.CHANNEL_ID, channelId)
            .execute();
    }

    public static void deleteLogChannel(long guildId) {
        getContext().deleteFrom(LOG_CHANNEL).where(LOG_CHANNEL.GUILD_ID.eq(guildId)).execute();
    }

    public static Long getLogChannelId(long guildId) {
        return getContext().selectFrom(LOG_CHANNEL)
            .where(LOG_CHANNEL.GUILD_ID.eq(guildId))
            .fetchOne(LOG_CHANNEL.CHANNEL_ID);
    }
```

```java
  private void handleSetCommand(@NotNull YusufSlashCommandEvent yusufSlashCommandEvent) {
        YusufGuild guild = yusufSlashCommandEvent.getGuild();
        long channelId = yusufSlashCommandEvent.getOption(ADD_CHANNEL).getAsLong();

        if (isChannelAlreadySet(guild.getIdLong(), yusufSlashCommandEvent)) {
            return;
        }

        if (!ModerationHelper.userAndBotHaveTheRightPerms(yusufSlashCommandEvent.getMember(),
                guild.getBot(), yusufSlashCommandEvent, guild, Permission.MANAGE_CHANNEL, SET)) {
            return;
        }

        setLogChannel(guild.getIdLong(), channelId);

        String textChannelName = Objects
            .requireNonNull(
                    yusufSlashCommandEvent.getGuild().getGuild().getTextChannelById(channelId))
            .getAsMention();

        yusufSlashCommandEvent.replyMessage("Log channel set to " + textChannelName);

        logger.info("Log channel set to {}", textChannelName);
    }

  private static boolean isChannelAlreadySet(long guildId, YusufSlashCommandEvent event) {
        if (isLogChannelSet(guildId)) {
            event
                .reply("The log channel is already set. Please change it with "
                        + "`/log_channel change <channel>`")
                .setEphemeral(true)
                .queue();
            logger.info("Log channel is already set");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is talking the channel and getting its id but when the id is taken its not stored and I dont why.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. If the ID is set your code immediately returns

Comment: if something isn't stored, then this is most likely due to some transaction rollback. Can you track this down in your code, and/or show the code that manages your transaction in this case?

Comment: I solved it. It was a problem caused by my database